# How to define a hierarchy of classes to inherit variables and methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I'm trying to find an efficient (code length, verbiage, readability) way to implement a material properties database.  Different properties are sometimes grouped. For instance, all Materials have a fatigue life, different material types have different fatigue resistance, different material grades have different stiffnesses.

```
class Material(object):

    def convert_c_to_f(self, temperature):
        blah = (temperature - 32) *5.0 / 9.0
        return blah

    def other_function(self, foobar):
        return foobar

class CarbonSteel(Material):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CarbonSteel, self).__init__()

    prop_one = 3.0
    prop_two = 0.2

    fatigue_constants = [     2.254510, -4.642236e-01, -8.312745e-01,
                          8.634660e-02,  2.020834e-01, -6.940535e-03,
                         -2.079726e-02,  2.010235e-04, 7.137717e-04,
                             0.0,                 0.0]

class SA105(CarbonSteel):

    def __init__(self):
        super(SA105, self).__init__()

    units = "imperial"

    nom_comp = "Carbon Steel"
    form = "Forging"
    P_no = "1"
    group = "2"

    min_tensile_ksi = 70
    min_yield_ksi = 36

    temp_list = [-20.0, 400.0, 500.0, 600.0, 650.0, 700.0, 750.0, 800.0, 850.0, 900.0, 950.0, 1000.0]
    temp_list = np.array(temp_list)
```

then the following fail:

```
    temp_list_c = temp_f2c(temp_list)
    temp_list_c = super().super().temp_f2c(temp_list)
```

When I define my object as having

```
self.material = SA105()
```

Then I can't go in and get the 'super' properties by:

```
self.material.super().fatigue_constants
```

At this point I'm a little lost.  I was trying to do a lot of things with these, referencing inherited methods and variables but I'm a little lost that way.

Was hoping to avoid copying all data into every class and then having to change errors in multiple locations if found.  I'm mainly using classes because of their inheritance properties but there may be a better way. (If methods weren't needed I can think of a few)

thanks!

EDIT: Tried to provide some more concrete examples.  Tried to do so without copying a huge slab of code.  If I shouldn't be using classes then let me know...

Comment: "I'm having problems" is too vague.  Please show the code where you use `SA105` and show what you try to do with it and what errors you get.

Comment: Could you please restructure the example you provided to actually show the issues you have? So far it's hard to tell what are your expectations and what's going wrong.

Comment: Steel and carbon steel would probably be instances of `Material`, rather than subclasses. Further, `Material` should define operations and store properties that are the same for any particular instance (fatigue constants, for example). Conversely, converting a temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit isn't something that belongs in the class, because it is completely independent of any particular material.

Comment: yes sorry edited the answer to give an example of what fails

Comment: I moved the method into the class because it was a common method for all materials

Comment: @chepner SA105 is a type of carbon steel, I have another which is also a carbon steel but they have different strengths.  How can I make an instance that inherits both properties?

Comment: True. I was going to suggest that `Material.__init__` should take those parameters, and the subclasses should then call `Material.__init__` with hard-coded arguments, and that led me to take one more (incorrect) step that steel et al. should be instances rather than subclasses.